# Query não retorna valores

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, query

Nenhuma das minhas querys retornam valores, sendo que possui dados no meu banco. O que pode estar havendo em meu código que está resultando nisso?
Segue o Código:

```
<?php
require_once("Usuario.php");
require_once("Conexao.php");
require_once("Crud.php");
class DaoUsuario implements Crud{
    private $status;
    private $tabela;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->$status = conexao::getConexao();
        $this->$tabela = "usuario";

    }

    public function consultar($id) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tabela} WHERE id=:id";
        try{
            $operacao = $this->status->prepare($query);
            $operacao->bindValue("id:",$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $operacao->execute();
            $getRow = $operacao->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $usuario = $getRow->usuario;
            $senha = $getRow->senha;
            $objeto = new Usuario($id, $usuario, $senha);
            $objeto->setId($id);
            return $objeto;
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            echo $erro->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function criar($objeto) {
        $id = $this->getNewIdUsuario();
        $usuario = $this->getUsuario();
        $senha = $this->getSenha();
        $query = "INSERT INTO {$this->tabela} (id,usuario,senha) VALUES(:usuario, :senha)";
        try{
            $operacao = $this->status->prepare($query);
            $operacao->bindValue(":id",$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $operacao->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $operacao->bindValue(":senha", $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($operacao->execute()){
                if($operacao->rowCount() > 0){
                    $objeto->setId($id);
                    return true;
                } else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            echo $erro->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function deletar($parametro) {
        $query = "DELETE FROM {$this->tabela} WHERE id=:id";
        try{
            $operacao = $this->status->prepare($query);
            $operacao->bindValue(":id",$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if($operacao->execute()){
                if($operacao->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            echo $erro->getMessage();

        }

    }

    public function modificar($objeto) {
        $id = $objeto->getId();
        $usuario = $objeto->getUsuario();
        $senha = $objeto->getSenha();
        $query = "UPDATE {$this->tabela} SET usuario=:usuario, senha=:senha WHERE id=:id";
        try{
            $operacao = $this->status->prepare($query);
            $operacao->bindValue(":id",$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $operacao->bindValue(":usuario",$usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $operacao->bindValue(":senha",$senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($operacao->execute()){
                if($operacao->rowCount() > 0){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            echo $erro->getMessage();

        }

    }
    private function getNewIdUsuario(){
        $query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM {$this->tabela}";
        try{
            $operacao = $this->status->prepare($query);
            if($operacao->execute()){
                if($operacao->rowCount() > 0){
                    $getRow = $operacao->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $idReturn = (int) $getRow->id + 1;
                    return $idReturn;
                }else{
                    throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro no Banco de Dados");
                    exit();
                }
            }else{
                throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro no Banco de Dados");
                exit();
            }
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            echo $erro->getMessage();

        }
    }

}
```

Quando vou fazer uma sessão:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../Classes/DaoUsuario.php');

    $autentificar = new DaoUsuario;
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        $autentificar->consultar($id);
        if(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($autentificar)>1){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('Location: painel-de-controle.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: administrador.php');
        session_destroy();
    }
?>
```

Minha conexão:

```
<?php
class Conexao {
   private static $conexao;
   private function __construct(){}
   private function __clone() {}
   private function __wakeup() {}

   public static function getConexao(){
       if(!isset(self::$conexao)){
           try{
            $banco = 'mysql:host=meu_servidor;dbname=nome_banco';
            $usuario = 'meu_usuario';
            $senha = 'minha_senha';
       }catch (PDOException $erro){
       echo $erro->getMessage();
       //Encerrando
       exit();
            }
        } 
       return self::$conexao;
    }
}
```

E retorna o seguinte erro:
Fatal error: **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in DaoUsuario.php on line 18**

Comment: Pelo jeito não fez a conexão corretamente, de uma olhada em usuário, senha e nome do banco.

Comment: Para facilitar de encontrar os erros quando tiver nome do arquivo e linha, indica nos códigos os nomes dos arquivos de cada um, e comenta na linha que aquela é a linha 18 que o erro fala! Tua conexão está retornando null, verifica as credenciais do banco e o host e qualquer coisa mostra o código da função `conexao::getConexao();`

Comment: Vou reformular minha pergunta para mostrar a conexão...

Comment: Está normal, só se haver algum erro de sintaxe onde não estou vendo (os nomes verdadeiros ocultei por questões de segurança)

Comment: `$this->$status` deveria ser `$this->status`

Comment: Eu mudei e não ocorreu nenhuma alteração (retornando nulo ainda)

Comment: Gente, muito obrigado, estava faltando algumas coisas na minha conexão. Por mais que deu outro erro (na parte de sessões do php) já me ajudaram bastante. Valeu pessoal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pouco conheço PHP e o framework que você utiliza, mas olhando brevemente, seu objeto `$this->status` resultado de `conexao::getConexao()` está nulo.
Verifique o retorno da chamada de `conexao::getConexao()`.

Comment: Então, não está retornando nada, mas o incrível que está normal, tanto que não há erro de sintaxe quando abro minha IDE

Comment: Já consegui resolver. Obrigado Tetri!

Comment: legal @Novato, se minha resposta o auxiliou na resolução, marque-a como solução.